# Get integer value against Picker.Items in Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my code in xaml

```
<Picker Title="Privacy" SelectedItem="{Binding PrivacyLevel}">
  <Picker.Items>
      <x:String>Public</x:String>
      <x:String>Private</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

The property **PrivacyLevel** is of integer type. I want to store 1 if public and 2 if Private. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class to represent your items, maybe a `PrivacyLevel` class. Instead of binding your Picker against a string's list you can use a `List<PrivacyLevel>`. PrivacyLevel class contains both, the text you want to display and the value you want to persist/store/use.

```
public class PrivacyLevel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate your ViewModel with the options.

```
    public List<PrivacyLevel> Privacies { get; set; } = new List<PrivacyLevel>()
    {
        new PrivacyLevel(){Name = "Public",Value = 1},
        new PrivacyLevel(){Name = "Private",Value = 2}
    };

    private PrivacyLevel _privacy;
    public PrivacyLevel Privacy{
       get{
          return _privacy;
       }
       set{
          _privacy=value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
       }
    }
```

And finally,

```
    <Picker Title="Privacy"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Privacies}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Privacy}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

> Remeber that now you have a **SelectedItem** which is an object and if you want to use the Value, you need access to its property.

Comment: bit confused,
Where I have defined my text "Public" and "Private" in this code?
and What is Privacies & Privacy in your code?

Comment: You can use a class to represent your items, maybe a PrivacyLevel class. Instead of binding your Picker against a string's list you can use a `List<PrivacyLevel>`. PrivacyLevel class contains both, the text you want to display and the value you want to persist/store/use.

Comment: Its working fine but i am bit confused with implementing notification changes. due to which it is getting every time 0.

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to keep UI and BindingContext in sync.  You can review it here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/